# How do you make spring-mvc-test framework stop trapping exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am using the Spring MVC Test framework in Spring 3.2.4, and one problem I have with it is that it continuously traps exceptions. For example, if you perform a POST with JSON data (or anything really), and a `NullPointerException` or Jackson `MappingException` is thrown, it doesn't just report it in the console output like a regular test - it traps it and does something else with it - or sometimes suppresses it altogether and forces me to create temporary `@ExceptionHandler` methods in my controllers or manually invoke `andDo(print())` just to see what went wrong.

How can I get spring-mvc-test framework to just report errors like any other test? I use IntelliJ IDEA, and I just want to see the exception stack track and have full clickability with respect to line numbers and such offered by the IDE. Without this most basic testing feature, creating and debugging tests with Spring MVC test framework is actually really a pain.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please show your setup with an SSCCE.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Show your code, config files. [Do it with an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I don't think my situation is unique. I think this is how the test framework functions by default. What files do you want me to include? Spring projects have so much stuff you have to put up here.

Comment: That's why you provide an SSCCE. Give the minimum configuration that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you use the spring mvc test framework and have different results, or have you never used it? I am not opposed to giving wads of specifics, but I think my question may be a lot simpler than that.